# How to send a list of items to a form in selenium and press return for each item in that list?

Tags: python, selenium

Apologies if the title isn't 100% clear. Basically what I want to do is send every item in a list to the same form but for each item, hit 'RETURN' then continue onto the next item, send_keys again, hit RETURN again and so on.

This is what I have so far

```
driver.find_element_by_name("website").send_keys(urls, Keys.RETURN)
```

This would send all items in the urls list and then hit return, when what I want to do is hit return for each element in that list.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for loop:

```
for url in urls:
    driver.find_element_by_name("website").send_keys(url, Keys.RETURN)
```

Use `WebDriverWait` to wait until element will be clickable:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ..
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for url in urls:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "website"))).send_keys(url, Keys.RETURN)
```

You can also use `\ue007` - **Enter** key code, that Selenium Keys implementation uses, but this is for a very specific issue. Normally `WebDriverWait` is better solution, because website do something with every enter:

```
urls = [
    "https://aa.com\ue007",
    "https://bb.com\ue007",
    "https://cc.com\ue007"
]
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("website").send_keys(urls)
```

Comment: With using this I get this error after one run 'selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable'. Is this protection the website has implemented? If so is there an option to add a delay in the loop? Thank you again!

Comment: `WebDriverWait` should solve the problem, check the answer update

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does exactly what I want.:)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to loop through your list to do it:

```
for url in urls:

     driver.find_element_by_name("website").send_keys(url, Keys.RETURN)
```

I suspect that this may enter one url, hit return and then send the next one to replace it.  If you are wanting this entire list of url's to be entered into a field then you may need to build a string placing line returns in between each url and then sending that one object like this:

```
urlList = ""

for url in urls:
     urlist = urlist + url + "\r\n"

driver.find_element_by_name("website").send_keys(urlList)
```